# smart_str_alloc: error: newlen undeclared

Tags: php-internals

I'm using the `smart_str` headers for a short FastCGI script (not related to PHP), but can't use `smart_str_alloc` correctly. My code:

```
smart_str json = {0, 0, 0};
smart_str_alloc(&json, 1024 * 20, 0);
```

This gives error:

```
php_smart_str.h:72:37: error: ‘newlen’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  smart_str_alloc4((d), (n), (what), newlen)
```

And the macro for `smart_str_alloc4` is:

```
#define smart_str_alloc4(d, n, what, newlen) do {                   \
    if (!(d)->c) {                                                  \
        (d)->len = 0;                                               \
        newlen = (n);                                               \
        (d)->a = newlen < SMART_STR_START_SIZE                      \
                ? SMART_STR_START_SIZE                              \
                : newlen + SMART_STR_PREALLOC;                      \
        SMART_STR_DO_REALLOC(d, what);                              \
    } else {                                                        \
        newlen = (d)->len + (n);                                    \
        if (newlen >= (d)->a) {                                     \
            (d)->a = newlen + SMART_STR_PREALLOC;                   \
            SMART_STR_DO_REALLOC(d, what);                          \
        }                                                           \
    }                                                               \
} while (0)
```

The `newlen` argument is passed from the `smart_str_alloc` definition like so:

```
#define smart_str_alloc(d, n, what) \
    smart_str_alloc4((d), (n), (what), newlen)
```

Funny thing is, in the PHP source code, `smart_str_alloc` is used without problem (from `json.c`):

```
smart_str_alloc(buf, len+2, 0);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The macro `smart_str_alloc` needs a defined variable `newlen` in it's scope:

```
size_t newlen;
```